# Construir un Mat Flat Tree a partir de un datos recuperados de una bd en Angular

Tags: angular, angular7, angular6, angular8

Hola tengo un problema para mostrar datos en el componente MAT-TREE de Angular Material. Desde la base de datos obtengo un array como el siguiente:

[image: datos obtenidos desde la base de datos]

y mi objetivo es transformarlo en lo siguiente:

```
  const TREE_DATA = {
  'FACULTADES': {
    'CIENCIAS INFORMÁTICAS': {
      'INFORMÁTICA': null
    },
    'CIENCIAS ADMINISTRATIVAS': {
      'CONTABILIDAD Y AUDITORIA': null,
      'HOTELERIA Y TURISMO': null
    },
  }
};
```

Lo que quiero es mostrar todas las categorías y subcategorías recuperada desde la bd en la vista, haciendo similar como esto:

[image: arbol]

He intentado hacer algo con algunos bucles Foreach, pero además de ser poco eficiente, no obtenía el resultado que buscaba. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar de la manera más optima para poder realizar esa transformación?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He pasado algunos días buscando alguna solución a mi problema, y terminé haciendo lo siguiente:

```
buildTree(categorias: any[], subcategorias: Subcategorias[]) {
    const Json = { 'FACULTADES': {} };
    categorias.forEach(categoria => {
      Json.FACULTADES[categoria] = {};
      subcategorias.forEach(subcategoria => {
        if (subcategoria.categorias === categoria) {
          (Json.FACULTADES[categoria])[subcategoria.subcategorias] = null;
        }
      });
    });
    this.Tree = Json;
  }
```

Espero que si alguien tiene un problema similar le sea útil. Saludos...